# Procedure result with XML parsing error

Tags: parsing, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to use my first procedure. I need it for Google Matrix. This is my procedure, found there

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateDistanceGoogle] 
    (@ToAddress NVARCHAR(100), 
     @FromAddress NVARCHAR(100), 
     @DistanceistanceInKm FLOAT OUTPUT) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Object INT 
    DECLARE @ResponseonseText NVARCHAR(4000) 
    DECLARE @StatuserviceUrl NVARCHAR(500)

    SET @StatuserviceUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=' + @ToAddress + '&destinations=' + @FromAddress +'&mode=driving&language=it-IT&units=metric;'

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT; EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @StatuserviceUrl, 'false' EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send' EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseonseText OUTPUT

    DECLARE @Response XML

    SET @Response = CAST(CAST(@ResponseonseText AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML)

    DECLARE @Status NVARCHAR(20) DECLARE @Distance NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @Status = @Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/status)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')

    IF(@Status = 'ZERO_RESULTS') 
       SET @Distance = NULL 
    ELSE 
       SET @Distance = @Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')

    SET @DistanceistanceInKm = ROUND(CAST(@Distance AS FLOAT) / 1000, 1)

    PRINT @DistanceistanceInKm
END
```

And this is the execution to store result of distance in the variable:

```
DECLARE @Distanza NVARCHAR 
EXEC @Distanza = dbo.CalculateDistanceGoogle @ToAddress = 'CITY', @FromAddress='CITY',  @DistanceistanceInKm = @Distanza
PRINT @Distanza
```

I get this error:

> Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CalculateDistanceGoogle, Line
>   13
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

Can you help me to understand why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Google is returning the XML encoded as UTF-8 and SQL Server only handles and stores UTF-16 (Little Endian) for both `XML` and `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` data.

I used the following URL:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Boise+ID&destinations=Casper+WY&mode=driving&language=en-US
```

and received the following response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <origin_address>Boise, ID, USA</origin_address>
 <destination_address>Casper, WY, USA</destination_address>
 <row>
  <element>
   <status>OK</status>
   <duration>
    <value>36626</value>
    <text>10 hours 10 mins</text>
   </duration>
   <distance>
    <value>1103852</value>
    <text>1,104 km</text>
   </distance>
  </element>
 </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

So, in a very simplistic sense, you could "fix" this by simply removing the `encoding="UTF-8"` string from the XML document before converting it to `XML`. You can do this by adding the following line just above the `SET @Response = CAST(...` line:

```sql
SET @ResponseonseText = REPLACE(@ResponseonseText, N'encoding="UTF-8"', N'');
```

Just keep in mind that certain characters coming through as UTF-8 *might* get mangled when store in an `NVARCHAR` variable. But perhaps that part is already taken care of by `sp_OAMethod`, in which case you don't need to worry about that.

Also:

- According to the [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro), you are supposed to pass in an API "key" parameter. Yet somehow it does appear to be working, at least in a limited sense, without it.
- You should consider moving away from the `sp_OA*` OLE Automation procedures as they were deprecated when SQL Server 2005 was introduced. The preference to is move such functionality to SQLCLR. (of course, if you are still using SQL Server 2005, that has also been deprecated for a while now ;-)
- Even though the OLE object should be automatically cleaned up when the Stored Procedure exits, it is probably still a good idea to add a line for: [sp_OADestroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173866.aspx) `@Object`
- The `@ResponseonseText` should be declared as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`
- You should remove the `CAST` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for `@ResponseonseText` as it is useless. Even if you have to keep that variable as `NVARCHAR(4000)`, the `CAST` to `MAX` doesn't really do anything.
- You might want to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top of the Stored Procedure, just after the `BEGIN`.
- You should wrap this in a `TRY...CATCH` construct.

Comment: -  I add the UTF 8 line replace and now it don't give me error but I've a print result = 0. What can be still wrong?    -  How I need to replace the sp_OA with SQLCLR? If I replace directly it, it give me an error for a not created table.

Comment: - I've removed the cast - I've set the nocount - I don't understand why the try and catch?